# Embedded Electron on NXP i.MX6

Tags: linux, embedded, electron, yocto, nxp-microcontroller

Earlier this year, I developed an app with the framework Electron (made by Github) and now I would like to embed it on a SBC I bought. 
The SBC is the ConnectCore6 from DIGI, based on the NXP i.MX6 processor, and connected to a screen with HDMI.

I can generate linux images for this SBC with Yocto and load GTK & QT applications on it. However, I would like to understand if create a compatible version of my Electron app for this hardware is an easy, hard or impossible task.

I don't realize what is needed by Electron to work on PCs (Windows, Linux and OS X) and should be set up on the SBC to get the same result.

Could you help me with that and possibly guide me to find a way to execute the Electron App on the board ?

Thank you

Antoine

Comment: You mentioned that you are using Yocto. It might be worthwhile to have a look at this Yocto layer which provides recipes for Electron. https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-electron

Comment: Thank you Frank, I'm going to test this layer and keep you informed :)

Comment: The original question aside, how's the performance of your Electron app running on i.MX6?

Answer (score 1):

The job can be quite easy.

You can simply configure your tools (e.g. qt creator) to use cross compiler and cross libs of Yocto SDK.

Looking at the [Electron web site](http://electron.atom.io/docs/development/build-instructions-linux/) I found

> **Cross compilation**
>   If you want to build for an arm target you should also install the following >dependencies:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-armhf-cross linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross \
>                        g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
> ```
>
> And to cross compile for arm or ia32 targets, you should pass the --target_arch parameter to the bootstrap.py script:
>
> ```
> $ ./script/bootstrap.py -v --target_arch=arm
> ```

---

The main problem is if a lib, required by Electron framework, is not available as open source or already cross compiled. In that case you'll have to ask it to the lib provider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cross-compiled Electron as described on Electron website and loaded the generated "dist" repository on my SBC.
After that, I copied on the board the Electron Quick Start example (see https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and I tried to execute it.
Unfortunately, it seems that my linux image is missing a library because I got the following message : `dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: It is something about x11 package. You should try to see if you can find it cross compiled for armv7 arch. Try to see [here armv7 versions](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libXss.so.1). BTW maybe yocto has a recipe for this lib. I'll try to check

Comment: Well you should provide it using Yocto, adding libxscrnsaver recipe as dependence.

Comment: I tried to install `libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-10.fc24.armv7hl.rpm` and `libXss1-1.2.2-9.1.2.armv7hl.rpm` with the command `rpm -ivh ...` but it doesn't seem to work either. I'm gonna try to generate an image with libxscrnsaver recipe.
I also downloaded `libxss_1.2.2.orig.tar.gz` to try to cross-compile it with the SBC toolchain. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For information, I finally generated the new image with libxscrnsaver. `libXss.so.1` and `libXss.so.1.0.0` can now be found at `/usr/lib` on the board but when I try to launch my Electron app, I have the following message : `./dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
Do you know if there is a way to determine which libraries are needed by Electron ? If not, I will have to put the new library in Yocto conf., rebuild the image and test again and again.
Thanks :)

Comment: You should add `nss` dependency in your Yocto recipe. BTW take note this is a process by successive approximation.

Comment: What do you mean with Yocto conf? You can simply add libs into a key into your recipe: `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nss lib1 lib2 "`

Comment: That is exactly what i'm doing :)
Actually, my *.conf contains `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libxscrnsaver"`. I'll add nss, lib1 and lib2. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't know if putting it into your local.conf work the same as putting into recipe. Into recipe the process will simply fecth compile and deply the new lib into your footfs. It is pretty fast, as far as the lib is not too big (i.e qt4e).

Comment: Looking at the electron layer linked by @FrankMeerkötter, the [main recipe](https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-electron/blob/master/recipes-electron/electron/electron_git.bb) gives you all inside DEPENDS key. Add all those to your recipe/conf file and rebuild it. Or add that layer to your configuration and add the electron recipe to your recipe.

Comment: I tried the second solution. I added the `path_to/meta-electron` to the variable `BBLAYERS` in my `bblayers.conf`file and the `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " electron"` in my local.conf.
I thought it will be enough but when I try to build the image I get the following message : `ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'clang-cross-arm' (but /home/dell/workspace/ccimx6sbc/meta-electron/recipes-electron/electron/electron_git.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  gdb-cross-arm
  gcc-cross-arm`
After the `bitbake` command. Do you have an idea to solve this ?

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/kraj/meta-clang) should do the trick. BTW you can also try removing clang reference if you want to use gcc only.

Comment: This is me again. I'm trying to make it works with the meta-clang layer added but the compilation of the target image never works. Clang `do_configure` doesn't work because of the CMake version used. I get :
`CMake 3.4.3 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.3.1`
Do you know how to easily upgrade the CMake version used by bitbake ? Thank you

Comment: Try updating the cmake meta recipe with the [latest here](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake?id=3c41b239991baff2bb1facc1e9973c95c9328175)

Comment: I added Clang layer and updated CMake to its last version, as you recommended. But I got errors like `No recipes available for rng-tools and musl`. I found them by following the last link you gave me and tried to add them to my existing layers.
And now, I have errors like `ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'bsd-headers-dev' (but /usr/local/dey-2.0/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/musl/musl_git.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)` that I don't understand at all. This error occurs for `bsd-headers-dev` and `musl-dev`. Do you have an idea ? Thanks.

Comment: It is (a pain ....ss) hard to update an old branch with updated recipes. The bsd-headers-dev should be [this one](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/bsd-headers?id=3c41b239991baff2bb1facc1e9973c95c9328175)

Comment: Oh ... I'm afraid hard part is coming :(
I added the `bsd-headers repo` found in your link but the `bsd-headers-dev` error is still here. What is the difference between `bsd-headers` and `bsd-headers-dev` ? I have the same problem with `musl` and `musl-dev` ...
Also, a new error appeared : `ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'bsd-headers' (but /usr/local/dey-2.0/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/musl/musl_git.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: bsd-headers was skipped: incompatible with host arm-dey-linux-gnueabi (not in COMPATIBLE_HOST)`

Comment: It seems na hard problem. Y can suggest you to download the whole meta layer and try with that.

Comment: Ok. I think I get where the problem is. `meta-electron` has 4 dependencies : `openembedded-core`, `meta-openembedded`, `meta-clang` and `meta-browser`. Also, `meta-clang` depends on `openembedded-core` and `bitbake`. Finally, `meta-browser` depends on `openembedded-core` and `meta-openembedded`. Consider all of them on their respective master branch.
OR, DIGI provides these layers on `jethro` branch (and `poky` instead of `openembedded-core`). I don't know if it's possible to make clang and electron work if it uses `poky` layer instead of `openembedded-core` layer...

Comment: I meant [these layers](http://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001945-13/default.htm#reference/yocto/r_system_development_yocto.htm%3FTocPath%3DDigi%2520Embedded%2520Yocto%7CSystem%2520development%7C_____0) !

Comment: I'm not getting you. I usually use both `poky/meta` and `poky/meta-yocto`, which contains qte recipes, and `openembedded`.